# Python - run all files in a folder and save input

Tags: python

I have a folder with hundreds of .py files. Each file contains a code that asks the user to input an integer, and then prints some other integer (each file is an assignment solution from a student in some university course).

I am looking for a way to run all the py files automatically, inputting a specific integer of my choice to all of them and checking if the printed output is correct.

I haven't found any solutions online, and the only thing I managed to think of was to create a list of all the paths to the py files and then use runfile (in spyder) on each of them in a loop. However, this still requires me to input the integer manually, and also I have no idea how to save the printed output so I could compare it to the correct expected output.

Comment: Does your solution need to be in python or just run python? This could be done pretty easily with a one line bash script.

Comment: use `glob` to get the paths of all the python files.  Then create result file names based on the input file names.  Then execute each file (python has various modules for this), with redirected stdin (to a file with your input data) and stdout (to the output file you just created a name for).  You will have a list of result files, named for their input files.